# Checking value of an index in an If statement Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement

Very new to Ruby and I am using an If statement to see if the value of an index is equal to an specific integer. I am given a string "12345" and want to see if the first char is equal to 1 so then I can delete it and post the array as a string again.

I convert the string to an array then check the value of the index[0]. I feel I am missing something very simple. Can anyone help?

```
def number
  num = ("12345")
  numArr = num.split("")

  if numArr.values_at(0) == 1
    numArr.shift
    numArr.join("")
  end
end
```

Comment: @AndrewLi A quote where? In my code? I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: Someone edited it in for you. Probably a copying error.

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer? If you select the first answer posted how do you know there won't be more helpful answers, or even if the answer you've selected is correct? Do you want to discourage other answers by quickly selecting the first one? What about the readers who are still working on their answers? Also, do you wish the original string to be modified or do you want to create a new string, leaving the original string unchanged?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I attempted each answer twice. The one I selected as "correct" happened to work for my given code. My goal, by selecting an answer so quickly, was to ensure that other people reading my question wouldn't waste time trying to help me and hopefully they can help others with their questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just work with the string directly no need to use split:

```
num = ("12345")

if num[0] == '1'
  num.slice!(0)
end

puts num
```

Output:

```
"2345"
```

Comment: 1. `num[0] == '1'` is simpler. 2. It may not be evident to the reader that the `if` statement returns the first character or `nil`, meaning that you cannot chain its return value. Better to use [String#slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-slice) as @Vimsha has done (or possibly [String#sub](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-sub) with the regex `/\A./`). If you wish to modify (or "mutate") the original string, use [String#slice!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-slice-21).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Can you please edit my answer to make it better for readers. I can't delete it because OP accepted it :(

Comment: You can edit it. You certainly could change `num[0].to_i == 1` to `num[0] == '1'`. You can also change `num.slice!(0)!(0)` to something else, as long you don't step on @Vimsha's toes. Consider using `sub` as I mentioned in my earlier comment.

Comment: My thought process for that was because OP mentioned  *first char is equal to 1* rather than *equal to '1'*

Comment: I think the OP meant `"1"`; regardless, characters in a string are strings, not integers. `num[0].to_i` equals `1` if and only if `num[0]` equals `'1'`, so the simpler form is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this

```
a.slice(1, a.length) if a[0] == "1"
```

your code would work too if you add quotes around 1 in your if condition

Comment: Very good. It's curious that you used `a` as the name of the variable holding a string. Perhaps you ran out of `s`'s (`s = `, `str = `,...)  :-)

Comment: `a.slice(1, a.length)` can also be written as `a.slice(1..-1)` or `a[1..-1]`